# Chapter without number has incorrect header

Tags: sectioning, fancyhdr

I am including a chapter without a number using `\chapter*{...}`. However, for some reason, when I do this it displays the wrong header on the next page. See the MWE below. On page 2 it should say 'Introduction' at the top right hand corner. But instead, it says 'List of Tables' currently. Is there a solution to this?

[image]

My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{newtxtext} 
\usepackage[a4paper,top=30mm,bottom=30mm,inner=30mm,outer=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{sectsty} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.36}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}% load after the other packages

\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}
              {\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\fontfamily{qhv}\selectfont}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{15pt}{\Huge}[\vspace{0.8ex}{\titlerule[2pt]}]

\allsectionsfont{\fontfamily{qhv}\selectfont}

\makeatletter % Removes the word 'Chapter'
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{}
\makeatother


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{}
\setlength{\headheight}{30pt}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}  
\blindtext[5]

\chapter{First Numbered Chapter}
\section{Example section}
\subsection{Example subsection}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\markboth{}{}`

Comment: @Johannes_B doesn't that leave the header empty?

Comment: Is `\markboth{Introduction}{}` needed?

Comment: @Johannes_B the question indicates it

Comment: @naphaneal Yes. I did not read the question. Just the title.